# Undeleted answer which was accepted after bounty started didn't get the bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I had this situation.

1. User asked question
2. I answered question
3. After some time I didn't get reply or any points so I deleted it.
4. User started bounty on his question
5. I undelete my answer and improve it
6. User accepts my answer
7. I don't get bounty after graceful period. Because technically my answer was created before bounty started.

I understand that from code point of view this is straight forward case. But may be it should take deletion and undeletion into account?

Because I can just create new answer with same content and get this bounty

Comment: Why did you delete your answer in the first place?

Comment: @Hayt 3 point. Because I didn't get any reply or points. I sometimes cleanup my answers with 0 points

Comment: Just because they maybe have no upvotes or comments to them does not make them bad or not helpful. A lot of people just see the right answer and forget about the question without accepting or upvoting. But they may be helpful for others who stumble upon this problem. You should maybe consider not deleting those when you think they will help others. You can also get upvotes later if someone else stumbles across them and finds them helpful.

Comment: Not related to your question here, but to add to the "why did you delete" comments.... I've been helped plenty of times by zero-score answers.  You shouldn't delete them just for the sake of deleting.  As long as the answer is accurate and correct, someone may benefit from it.  Heck, I've even have had downvoted posts help me (usually with helping me find the start of a different approach or with what not to do).

Comment: Same here. I just stumbled across a 0 score answer because it showed a new-modern and better way to a old question so I also upvoted this.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I agree with comments. above. Maybe I shouldn't have deleted it. But I don't get where is downvote comes from. It is perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: downvotes on meta just indicate disagreement to your feature request. Not what your question is bad or anything.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev downvotes on meta don't count in any way for anything, so don't worry about them.  But if you read [What's meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), you will see a section called "Voting is different on meta." - essentially voting, especially on feature requests can be used to express agreement or disagreement with the feature

Comment: @Hayt ah. Understood. I think it is weird behavior. Because I can just create new answer with same content and get this bounty

Comment: I mean the bounty can also be awarded to answers before creation date. The creation date is only important for new ones when the person who gave the bounty does not award it manually. So when your answer is good enough in the eyes of the bounty giver the creation date should not matter.

Comment: Well, live and learn.  Next time just re-post the improved answer instead of undeleting it.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, but won't it be like cheating or something? Because doing it this way I feel like I'm bending the rules.

Comment: Meh, you are a programmer.  So you should be used to finding a workaround for a clumsily programmed machine and not call it "cheating" :)

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev how much did you "improve" the answer?  Was it a major overhaul?  Or just a few minor changes?  Or somewhere in-between?  If it is really a different answer than the one you posted originally, then reposting it is certainly acceptable

Comment: @psubsee2003 I gave more detailed explanation and gave second solution. Maybe you are right I should have posted it as separate answer.

Comment: Based on `"If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration"` ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)) your un/deletion is irrelevant and you should have received the bounty just by virtue of having your answer accepted during the bounty period, assuming the OP didn't manually award it to someone else.

Comment: @henry you are reading that incorrectly....  "...accepts an answer **posted during the bounty period**".  It still requires it to be posted during the bounty period.  This one was post before the bounty period

Comment: Oh @psubsee2003 you're right I skipped right over "posted" and reading "accepts an answer during…"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is should bounty system take deletion into account.

No. Why? Read on:

> After some time I didn't get reply or any points so I deleted it.

That's not a good reason to delete an answer.

If your answer didn't provoke upvotes, acceptance, or comments... so what? You either improve the answer or you move on. You don't delete the answer just because it was not considered remarkable by people who read it.

Answer deletion is not meant for hiding something nobody noticed. It's for getting rid of content that's wrong, accidentally posted, spam, or other such things. Your answer did not quality; it simply wasn't found to be good enough to upvote or accept.

So I see no reason why the bounty awarding system should treat your improper deletion as the equivalent of posting a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the deletion & undeletion is only part of the story.  You said you improved it, which means the answer that was accepted wasn't really the answer you undeleted.

Now, what if you never deleted your answer and just improved it after the bounty was posted?  Would you expect the system judge your post as new and hence qualifying for the automatic award?  How much of an edit is necessary for the system to judge it as new?

---

The way the bounty system is designed is automatic award is based on a series of assumptions.  The first major assumption the system makes is if any existing answer was good enough, the bounty would not have been needed.  That is why existing answers are exempt from the automatic award - but it doesn't stop the bounty offerer from manually awarding the bounty.

The fact that you deleted it is immaterial.  It existed before.  The system then assumes that your answer wasn't good enough (and possibly why you deleted it in the first place), so automatically awarding to that answer would be against the wishes of the user who placed the bounty to begin with.

Now, editing the answer is a different story, but also makes it impossible to judge from an auto-award perspective.  You edited your answer significantly enough [by your own admission](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336458/undeleted-answer-which-was-accepted-after-bounty-started-didnt-get-the-bounty#comment405365_336458) that maybe it could have been a different answer.

- But what about someone who adds a few characters?  Should that reset the bounty status?  How many characters is enough to make it a good edit vs just a small change?
- What if the small change is significant enough to change the answer completely?
- What if someone makes a significant (but mostly irrelavant) edit?  Should that count?
- What if someone else makes the edit?

Allowing the edit to reset the bounty status and make additional assumptions about the nature of the change to automatically award a bounty.  That seems to violate the primary assumption to not auto-award the bounty to an answer that the user who offered the bounty did not want to award it too.